# Django: Writing tests for template tag

Tags: python, django

I am using [django-qr-code](https://github.com/dprog-philippe-docourt/django-qr-code) to generate QR codes. I wonder how to write a test if the QR code generation works properly. Do you have any tips?

```
<img src="{% qr_url_from_text attendee.ticket_code size='M' %}" alt="Ticket QR code">
```

More specifically if the template tag is e.g. `{% qr_url_from_text 'Hello World!' size='M' %}` the 'output' should be: `/qr_code/images/serve_qr_code_image/?text=SGVsbG8gV29ybGQyIQ%3D%3D&size=M`

Comment: Which test do you want to write? Functional test or unit test?

Comment: I want to test if the QR code picture is generated. I think in that case unit test?

Comment: More specifically if the template tag is e.g. `{% qr_url_from_text 'Hello World!' size='M' %}` the 'output' should be: /qr_code/images/serve_qr_code_image/?text=SGVsbG8gV29ybGQyIQ%3D%3D&size=M

Comment: You can simply write test finding your target url in your html. It's not spetial for template tag.